# uploadfile windows form C# web service

Tags: c#, web-services, file-upload, webclient

i'm new here,

help me out here please,

i am working with web service and doing upload file.

here's my code for uploading file

```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        testServiceClient = new TestServiceClient();

        var uploadFile = "C:\\Computer1\\Sample.csv";

        try
        {
            var dir = @"\\Computer2\UploadedFile\";
            string myUploadPath = dir;
            var myFileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadFile);

            var client = new WebClient { Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials };

            client.UploadFile(myUploadPath + myFileName, "PUT", uploadFile);
            client.Dispose();

            MessageBox.Show("ok");

            testServiceClient.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }

    }
```

i can upload file in the same network, but my question is this,

how can i upload file when the two computer is not in the same network?

i've tried changing the

```
var dir = @"\\Computer2\UploadedFile\";
```

to

```
var dir = @"https://Computer2/UploadedFile/";
```

but i'm getting an error 'unable to connect to remote server'

help me out here pls.

Answer (score 3):

In windows:

```
private void uploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    var dialogResult = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();    
    if (dialogResult != DialogResult.OK) return;              
    Upload(openFileDialog.FileName);
}

private void Upload(string fileName)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    var uri = new Uri("https://Computer2/UploadedFile/");  
    try
    {
        client.Headers.Add("fileName", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName));
        var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        client.UploadDataAsync(uri, data);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

In server:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<object> UploadedFile()
{
    var file = await Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    var fileName = Request.Headers.GetValues("fileName").FirstOrDefault();
    var filePath = "/upload/files/";
    try
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath) + fileName, file);           
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ignored
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not actually sending the file with your `UploadFile()` method, you are just sending the file path. you should be sending the file bytes.

This link is quite usefull: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22985/Upload-Any-File-Type-through-a-Web-Service

Comment: i can upload the file within the network, but i can't when i change the dir to http...

Comment: because on the network the file can be seen over the network... So you have to send the bytes of the file directly.